# move a branch path in git (change its name, not its code)

Tags: git, renaming

we have a branch on remote called `release/service-release-2016`

I want to rename the branch to `release/completed/service-release-2016` for archiving and clarity.

How do I do this?

Everything I searched for interpreted this as moving around commits and the head, etc. - I'm thinking this is probably pretty easy.

Comment: Simply run `git branch -m release/service-release-2016 release/completed/service-release-2016`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to check out the remote branch to a temporary branch name locally, push to the new name on the remote, and then delete the remote branch. For example:

```
git checkout -b tmp origin/release/service-release-2016
```

Create the new remote branch:

```
git push origin tmp:release/completed/service-release-2016
```

Delete the old remote branch:

```
git push origin :release/service-release-2016
```